# Conflict between Groovy and Spock

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I'm using Spock 1.2-groovy-2.5, Groovy with version 2.5.3 and Java 8. Unfortunately I see this error:

```
Information:Groovyc: While compiling tests of alternativeworld: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-macro is loaded in version 2.5.3 and you are trying to load version 2.5.2
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:161)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.<clinit>(GrapeIvy.groovy:70)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.getInstance(Grape.java:123)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:157)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:376)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:320)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:976)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:651)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:627)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:604)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.lambda$runGroovyc$0(InProcessGroovyc.java:88)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-macro is loaded in version 2.5.3 and you are trying to load version 2.5.2
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:523)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModulesFrom(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    ... 34 more
```

I'm using maven.

I'm looking for answer for three hours but nothing. Do You have any ideas ?

Comment: Most likely an environment issue where incompatible jars are being used. In case of Maven - incompatible dependencies. Google "GroovyRuntimeException Conflicting module versions" for some of the causes/solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably this in your *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Simply remove the groovy dependency, because Spock has it already as a dependency on version 2.5.2 - here is the conflict. It means that you will have only this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or if you really want Groovy version 2.5.3 instead of 2.5.2 which is linked by Spock then you can exclude it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```